# Android media controller in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer, spotify

I am trying to create a section in my android launcher that should directly control audio playback(like songs on Spotify, Audible, Wink ,etc.) but creating it is harder than it seems.

after searching around on the topic i figured out that instead of different APIs for different music apps, i should just use notifications to control media being played by those apps but do i actually interact with it.

Also is there an alternative way of doing this,
as this functionality is common all earphones and headphones etc. so I assume there must be a easier way to implement it through some Android API.

---

As it turns out MediaSessionCompat is used by peripherals for playback control but there is no good example of using it with compose.

if any one have knowledge about it please share.

Comment: Nothing is harder unless you try.

Comment: thank you for replying. I am new to Compose and there are no resources on how to use mediasessioncompat with compose. mediasessioncompat is the thing used by headphones and earphones for playback controls